# Minimal Kinetic energy for particle in a box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

This is driving me crazy! The question goes as follows:

A proton is enclosed in a zone of length 2pm along the x-axis. The minimal kinetic energy of the proton lies closest to:

- 5000eV
- 0.5eV
- 50eV
- 500eV
- **5eV** (this is supposed to be the correct answer)

So first I calculate the energy level for a particle in a box which is given by the equation $E_n = p_n^2/(2 m) = (n^2 h^2)/(8 m L^2) $

Here $L$ is the length of the zone. So I find $E_1=94007.53 eV$..

So.. How do I relate this to the minimal kinetic energy?

-- EDIT 1 --

After the first hint from someone, I changed my calculations (I used the mass of an electron instead of a proton..) NOW I get $E_1 = 51eV$, which is still wrong..

Comment: It looks like you used the electron mass rather than the proton mass...

Comment: Owh god.. You're right -.- I've made like 30+ exercises on different subjects.. All of them, by coincidence, were related to electrons, so I'm so used to using that value as the mass of a sub-atomic particle that I didn't even think twice when using it here.. THANK YOU!

Comment: It's still not right though.. The new answer I become is $E_1 = h^2/(8*1.6726*10^-27*(2*10^(-12))^2)=51 eV$

Comment: Yes, I get the same. I'm thinking the suggested answer is wrong - you're doing the right thing.

Comment: But.. It's the answer our physics professor gave on one of his multiple choice questions on an example exam.. :( I guess he made a mistake;. Even though the 'name' of the one who filled in the exam is F. Lawless x') Thanks for checking it!

Comment: Also, when you do powers in LaTeX you need to do x^{yz}: $x^{yz}$.

Comment: You should mention it to him then. Sometimes they just change the numbers from year to year but miss changing it in one place.

Comment: @Spyral The mistake is in your formula for the energy calculation. You have missed out the division by pi^2 (pi = 3.14...). The equation reads E = h^2/(8pi^2 m_pL^2). So if you do your calculation including the division by pi^2 you will find the right answer. I hope this helps you?

Answer (score -1):

@Spyral The error in your calculation is that you have missed out the division by $\pi^2$ ($\pi$ = 3.14...).  The equation for the energy in the ground state (n = 1) is given by the equation

$E = h^2/(8\pi^2 m L^2)$

$h$ = Planck's constant; $m$ = mass of the proton in your case, $L$ = the length of the size of the box. If you use this equation (derived from Schrodinger equation) you will find the right answer, ~ 5eV. I hope this helps.

Comment: I get that the $\pi^2$ cancels out: $\frac{p^{2}}{2m}=\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\left(\frac{2\pi}{2L}\right)^{2}=\frac{h^2}{2m\left(2\pi\right)^{2}}\frac{\pi^{2}}{L^{2}}=\frac{h^2}{2m\left(2\right)^{2}} \frac{1}{L^{2}} $ Where is my mistake?

Comment: Also wikipedia disagrees with you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box

Comment: The wavefunction must have a node at $x=0$ and $x=L$, so $k L=\pi n$ where $n$ is an integer. So I get $ p = \hbar k = \hbar \pi / L = h/2L $. Thus $p^2 / 2m = \frac{h^2}{8 m L^2}$. Your wavefunction is incorrect since it has $k L = 1$, which does not give a node at $x=L$: $\sin( k x ) = \sin(1)\neq 0$. It's not just wiki: hyperphysics also disagrees with you: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/schr.html#c3, as does my calculation which uses the usual definition of the momentum and the requirement that the wavefunction is zero at $x=L$.

Comment: In fact, if I put the OP's numbers into the Hyperphysics calculator it gives the same answer 51.198... eV.

Comment: Quickly googling finds many references that disagree with you. This is such a basic problem that it is unlikely to find so many sources independently mistaken, but you don't have to take my word for it. Solve the Schrodinger equation yourself and apply the boundary conditions.

Comment: Oh, I see. I read you wrong and thought you meant the opposite of what you did - that the OP's calculation is wrong ("The error in your calculation is...") and the supplied answer is the correct one. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Yes of course you're right - factors of 2 and $\pi$ easily go wrong if you sloppily apply the uncertainty principle. I guess the main point for me is to reassure the OP that he was doing the right thing and that the supplied answer was in error. Whatever the source of that error may be is speculation, but your story makes sense. FYI the latex \hbar works here.